# populate dynamic list queryset with ausent values and merge it

Tags: python, django

I'm trying create a list with 12 months and yours respect value, but if month/value ausent I need create a default "0" and merged with dynamic data.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
_qs = CheckOut.objects.filter(date_service__year=datetime.datetime.now().year)\
    .values_list('date_service__month')\
    .annotate(total=Sum('checkoutitem__total_value'))\
    .order_by('date_service__month')

dt = OrderedDict(_qs)  # Wrap queryset with an OrderedDict

months = list(dt.keys())
valore = list(dt.values())
extra_context['profit'] = [months, valore]
```

And the result in template django:

```
 [[9, 10, 11], [Decimal('800.00'), Decimal('300.00'), Decimal('100.00')]]
```

So, I need create the months: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,12 and create the values (if not exists in queryset, default "0". And keep the Order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could simply work on the `dict` using [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
dt = OrderedDict(_qs)  # Wrap queryset with an OrderedDict

for i in range(1, 13):
    dt.setdefault(i, Decimal('0.00'))
```

This only inserts the value 0 if the key is not present.

---

EDIT

If you want it sorted and as strings, you could create a new dict; because its a small dict, the cost will almost be neglible compared to the query.

```
dt = OrderedDict(sorted(
    (k, str(v))
    for k, v in dt.items()))
```

This should use the `str()` of the `Decimal` numbers to get a string without the word "Decimal" in it.

Comment: thanks, works fine. How I reorder now, this is the result:
` [[9, 10, 11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12], [Decimal('800.00'), Decimal('300.00'), Decimal('100.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00')]]`

Comment: Thank you man! You're great. Last question, How I do to remove "Decimal" word, and put a list with the values [100,200,300, ... ] and not [Decimal(100.00), Decimal(200.00) ..]